# regex and replace on string using python

Tags: python, regex

I am rather new to Python Regex (regex in general) and I have been encountering a problem. So, I have a few strings like so:

```
str1 = r'''hfo/gfbi/mytag=a_17014b_82c'''
str2 = r'''/bkyhi/oiukj/game/?mytag=a_17014b_82c&'''
str3 = r'''lkjsd/image/game/mytag=a_17014b_82c$'''
```

the `&` and the `$` could be any symbol.

I would like to have a single regex (and replace) which replaces:

```
mytag=a_17014b_82c
```

to:

```
mytag=myvalue
```

from any of the above 3 strings. Would appreciate any guidance on how I can achieve this.

UPDATE: the string to be replaced is always not the same. So, `a_17014b_82c` could be anything in reality.

Comment: Is the string to be replaced always the same? In that case, you don't need a regex.

Comment: if these are url's as they appear to be, the `&` has special meaning so your statement that "the & and the $ could be any symbol" feels wrong.

Comment: the string to be replaced is not the same always :(

Comment: I would want it to always replace the value of `mytag` - if this makes sense. i.e `mytag` will always be present in the string.

Answer (score 1):

If the string to be replaced is constant you don't need a regex. Simply use `replace`:

```
>>> str1 = r'''hfo/gfbi/mytag=a_17014b_82c'''
>>> str1.replace('a_17014b_82c','myvalue')
'hfo/gfbi/mytag=myvalue'
```

Comment: Just posted an update - sorry, the string to be replaced is always not the same. Sorry for not being clear the first time around.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.sub`:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'(mytag=)(\w+)')
>>> r.sub(r'\1myvalue', str1)
'hfo/gfbi/mytag=myvalue'
>>> r.sub(r'\1myvalue', str2)
'/bkyhi/oiukj/game/?mytag=myvalue&'
>>> r.sub(r'\1myvalue', str3)
'lkjsd/image/game/mytag=myvalue$'
```

Comment: @Ashwini: This is awesome. Could you please explain why you use `\1`?

Comment: @JohnJ `\1` represents the first matching group i.e `'mytag='`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Thank you very much for your explanation. Accepted your answer! Was breaking my head over this for a couple of hours. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'(mytag=)\w+$')
r.sub(r'\1myvalue', str1)
```

This is based on @Ashwini's answer, two small changes are we are saying the `mytag=a_17014b` part should be at the end of input, so that even inputs such as

```
str1 = r'''/bkyhi/mytag=blah/game/?mytag=a_17014b_82c&'''
```

will work fine, substituting the last mytag instead of the the first.

Another small change is we are not unnecessarily capturing the `\w+`, since we aren't using it anyway. This is just for a bit of code clarity.