# Replace https://www. and http://www. using Python regex

Tags: python-3.x

I need to replace  https://www. , http://www. , http:// and https:// using Python3 regex for the below inputs;

Input:

```
 https://www.example.com/
 http://www.example.com/
 https://example.com/
 http://example.com/
```

Required output :

```
 example.com
```

Can anyone help me please since I am a beginner in Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex and replace on string using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043537/regex-and-replace-on-string-using-python)

Comment: it can be possible in your scenario `https://example.com/test/`?

Comment: If regex is not a requirement, you could just split the string like `'https://www.example.com/'.split('//')[1].split('/')[0]` or look into `urllib.parse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your suggestions and help. After going through the regex tutorials I managed to write the below code which gives me the expected result.

```
import re
domain = input("Enter the domain name : ")
stripped = 
re.sub(r'https://www\.|http://www\.|https://www|http://|https://|www\.', "", 
domain).strip('/')
print(stripped)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
string = "http://www.example.com"
pat = re.compile("https?://www.")
print(len(string))
val = pat.match(string)
if not val is None:
    print(string[val.end():])
else:
    print("no match")
```

should work for you.if you want to start understanding re stands for **Regular Expression** in python and `end` returns index of the last match.

`val` is None if there is no match.

Comment: I think it is required and change is not giving right results as `s` is an optional character that may appear once.

Comment: Oh yeah I see - then `https?` should do (optional single character)

Comment: What about the trailingslash at the end? that should be matched as-well right?

Comment: we can use `split('/')[0]` on the resulting string. I guess.

Comment: just see regex here. change it to `[www]?` for `www`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search('example.com', a)
>>> if m:
...     print(m.group(0))
```

where a is the text variable

Comment: it will not work for other domains though. i.e.., it could be any other site-name

Comment: Please have a check on my code, I believe its a simple one and gives the expected result. Kindly let me if it fails at any situations.